# Android ImageView setImageResource in code

Tags: android, imageview, android-resources

I have an imageView that I want to display a little icon of the country that you are currently in. I can get the country code, but problem is I can't dynamically change the imageView resource. My image files are all lowercase (Example: country code=US, image file=us)

My code (countryCode is the current countryCode in uppercase letters):

```
String lowerCountryCode = countryCode.toLowerCase();
String resource = "R.drawable." + lowerCountryCode;
img.setImageResource(resource);
```

Now, of course this will not work because `setImageResource` wants an `int`, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One easy way to map that country name that you have to an `int` to be used in the `setImageResource` method is:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(lowerCountryCode, "drawable", getPackageName());
setImageResource(id);
```

But you should really try to use different folders resources for the countries that you want to support.

Answer (score 35):

This is how to set an image into `ImageView` using the [**setImageResource()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) method:

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_play);
// supossing to have an image called ic_play inside my drawables.
myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
```

Answer (score 0):

you use that code

```
ImageView[] ivCard = new ImageView[1];

@override    
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  

ivCard[0]=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
// Create an array that matches any country to its id (as String):
String[][] countriesId = new String[NUMBER_OF_COUNTRIES_SUPPORTED][];

// Initialize the array, where the first column will be the country's name (in uppercase) and the second column will be its id (as String):
countriesId[0] = new String[] {"US", String.valueOf(R.drawable.us)};
countriesId[1] = new String[] {"FR", String.valueOf(R.drawable.fr)};
// and so on...

// And after you get the variable "countryCode":
int i;
for(i = 0; i<countriesId.length; i++) {
   if(countriesId[i][0].equals(countryCode))
      break;
}
// Now "i" is the index of the country

img.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(countriesId[i][1]));
```

Answer (score -2):

you may try this:-

```
myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_name));
```

Comment: That didn't help, getDrawable() wants an int as well when i am providing the "R.Drawable.image_name" as a string variable.. Any way around that?