# how to set background to imageView by imageview casted View?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to drop an image over an image and I have a code in which `View` is type casted by `ImageView` with `v.name` 'dropped' and this view will display on other `ImageView` named 'droptarget' as background but cant happend, plzz tell me a solution. my code is here.:

```
 case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

           //handle the dragged view being dropped over a target view

            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

            //stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged

            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //view dragged item is being dropped on

            ImageView dropTarget = (ImageView) v;

            //view being dragged and dropped

            ImageView dropped = (ImageView) view;

            //it give me error in this line

            **dropTarget.setBackgroundResource(dropped);**
```

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: the error is: The method setBackgroundResource(int) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (ImageView)

Answer (score 0):

You should give us more info about the code but anyway I'm going to suggest something.

I think you're calling setBackgroundResource on a null object. So you're mistake is on the next line

```
ImageView dropTarget = (ImageView) v;
```

There probably isn't a view called "v". Maybe you should change that?

Comment: sir there is a view parameter in onDrag() which i caste in ImageView and wana show it on other ImageView.

Comment: Here is the onDragListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html and yes you're right there is a view parameter.

Comment: sir this is the error: <br/>  The method setBackgroundResource(int) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (ImageView).<br/> so plz tell me that how can I typecaste View object so that i use that view object in setBackgroundRecources paramaters. and also view can't caste in Int.

Comment: According to the documentation the method is applicable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [ImageView.setImageResource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23257548/3885765). You can also set the backgroundImage, but best practice is to use setimageResource.

Comment: sir I try every option but it give same error. The method setBackgroundResource(int) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (ImageView)