# Fetching Icon name from database table as string and setting icon to image view

Tags: java, android

I am messing with it for quite along time now and not getting any sort of help from google or stackoverflow.

I stored icon names (which are in my drawable folder) in database as string like 
`ic_action_travel`.

What I want to do is setting icon to my imageview by using that name (`string`) like

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.+iconNameString);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android ImageView setImageResource in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646354/android-imageview-setimageresource-in-code)

Comment: @AlexLarionov yes it does, thanks